# What statistical analysis,model should I use for Likert-Scale data?

Tags: r, regression, likert

I am working in R and currently working on my thesis where I am analyzing if some factors have impact on purchasing behavior. 15 of the questions in my survey were were Likert Scale (1-5) and I would like to use them as independent variables. Total money spend would be dependent variable and I would also like to use income and gender and some other stuff as independent variable. What statistical analysis would you recommend me to analyze my data? I converted my Likert scale data into factor data with 5 levels and now I am lost.
Can I use OLS or would you recommend something else?
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: the most rigorous approach would be to use *ordinal* models (e.g see [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/))

Comment: @BenBolker If I was going to use ordinal model I would have to have also cathegorical (factor) as dependent variable or am I mistaken?  I would really like to have TotalMoneySpend as dependent variable and see how it changes based on what people chose at the likert scale questions/statements.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you have given I would recommend looking in to PLS (partial least squares) regression. It's a powerful method which will let you mix ordinal and scale variables and it allows for multicollinearity amongst your independent variables, which is often a fact for survey responses.